# when my python script uses a file for an argparse "args" my "if" statment is passed by

Tags: python, argparse

When I use --host=192.168.1.1 as an argument, this script works like a charm. When I use --host_file=asa.hosts, it fails because it seems to not be matching the "if hfile is True:". So this is obviously wrong. What would be a better term to match my --host_file=NAME.TXT

This is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "asaos-snmpv3-tool-hostfile.py", line 147, in <module>
  main()
   File "asaos-snmpv3-tool-hostfile.py", line 138, in main
   child = connect(user, host, passwd, en_passwd)
   File "asaos-snmpv3-tool-hostfile.py", line 47, in connect
   constr = 'ssh ' + user + '@' + host
  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

If it was failing, I would have expected it to error using "child = **connects**(user, **hosts**, passwd, en_passwd)"
If you look close, youll see that under my "if" I use **connects**, and **hosts** (plural), but it looks like its trying to parse the file under the main connect, and host.

```
def connect(user, host, passwd, en_passwd):
  ...output cut short

def connects(user, hosts, passwd, en_passwd):
  ...output cut short

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('usage %prog ' + '--host --host_file --username --password  --enable --group --snmp_user --snmp_host --int_name --snmp_v3_auth --snmp_v3_hmac --snmp_v3_priv --snmp_v3_encr')
  parser.add_argument('--host', dest='host', type=str, help='specify a target host')
  parser.add_argument('--host_file', dest='hfile', type=str, help='specify a target host file')

host = args.host
hfile = args.hfile
hosts = open(hfile, 'r')

for line in hosts.readlines():

    if hfile is True:
        hosts = line.strip('r').strip('\n')
        child = connects(user, hosts, passwd, en_passwd)
        send_command(child, SNMPGROUPCMD + group + V3PRIVCMD)
        send_command(child, SNMPSRVUSRCMD + snmpuser + ' ' + group + V3AUTHCMD + SHAHMACCMD + snmpauth + PRIVCMD + snmpencrypt + ' ' + snmppriv)
        send_command(child, SNMPSRVHOSTCMD + intname + ' ' + snmphost + VERSION3CMD + snmpuser)
        send_command(child, SNMPSRVENTRAP)
        send_command(child, WRME)
        exit()
child = connect(user, host, passwd, en_passwd)
send_command(child, SNMPGROUPCMD + group + V3PRIVCMD)
send_command(child, SNMPSRVUSRCMD + snmpuser + ' ' + group + V3AUTHCMD + SHAHMACCMD + snmpauth + PRIVCMD + snmpencrypt + ' ' + snmppriv)
send_command(child, SNMPSRVHOSTCMD + intname + ' ' + snmphost + VERSION3CMD + snmpuser)
send_command(child, SNMPSRVENTRAP)
send_command(child, WRME)
exit()
```

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: A few side notes: You can just do `for line in hosts:`; [calling `readlines()` just makes your code more verbose and less efficient for no benefit](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html). You should always `close` any files you `open`, ideally using a `with` statement instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Mostly working now, Thanks! One question, I'm getting and error that says --host_file "error: no such option: --host_file". It is there though, would you mind looking at my code on github and see if there is an obvious reason for this error? Thanks again! http://github.com/asrozar/ASAOS/blob/master/asaos-snmpv3-tool-hostfile.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `hfile` is either going to be a string, or `None`. Neither of those `is True`. Neither of those is even `== True`.

A non-empty string is truthy. `None` is not. Neither is a non-empty string. So, if you want to treat an empty string (e.g., `--host-file=''`) the same as no argument, just test `hfile` for truthiness:

```
if hfile:
```

If, on the other hand, you want to treat an empty string as a valid argument, test for `None`-ness:

```
if hfile is not None:
```

---

The reason you don't have this problem for `--host` is simple: You don't test `host` anywhere, so there's nowhere to get the test wrong.

---

However, maybe you *should* be testing `host` for `None`. I'm not sure what you actually want to do in that case, but you definitely don't want to call `connect(user, host, passwd, en_passwd)` with `None` for the `host`. That's why you're getting the exception, because the library is trying to concatenate all those strings together, and one of them isn't a string.

---

> If it was failing, I would have expected it to error using "child = connects(user, hosts, passwd, en_passwd)" If you look close, youll see that under my "if" I use connects, and hosts (plural), but it looks like its trying to parse the file under the main connect, and host.

But your `if` never triggers, so it doesn't matter what you do in that block. On the other hand the `connect` *always* runs, so that's what fails.

---

Finally, your logic makes no sense in the first place.

You go through the `hosts` file. For each line, you check `hfile`. If it's truthy, you will do a single connect and then `exit`. If it's not truthy, it will never become `truthy`, so you'll skip over all of the other lines as well. So, there is no way you could ever process any line beyond the first.

Also, inside that loop, you replace `hosts` with each line.

Also, you're stripping `r` instead of `\r`, and you're stripping it *before* `\n`, which means there would never be anything to strip even if you got it right.

And finally, you've got all that top-level code that comes after the `main` definition, and tries to use `main`'s local variables, and never even calls `main`. I suspect you may be mixing tabs and spaces, so what ends up pasted here doesn't match what you have in your original script; if so, it's almost guaranteed to cause problems that are hard to debug if you're lucky (and get an `IndentationError`) and nearly impossible if you're not (and just have the wrong flow control). Find a text editor that automatically turns tabs into spaces and/or shows tabs visually (almost anything but Notepad and TextEdit will do…), and test your scripts with the `-tt` flag just in case it slips past the editor.

Anyway, maybe you wanted something like [this](http://pastebin.com/M7GaJ4gP), but I'm really just guessing here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I cut a lot of code out, may be I should not have. I will look at your pastbin. Here is my full code if it helps.https://github.com/asrozar/Python-Scripts/blob/master/asaos-snmpv3-tool-hostfile.py

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused either `user` or `host` arguments to `connect` being `None`.

I do not see where you set `user`.

It looks like the `host` argument to `connect` comes from `args.host`.  If you have not given it a `--host` argument, the value of this will be the default `None`.

When debugging code using `argparse` I often `print args` just to make sure it is parsing the input as I expected.